uniform convergence of outer polygonal approximation of unit circle
Suppose we have the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$. We want to approximate the circle from the outside by polygons, to be exact I will describe our idea of constructing the polygon for given $N\in\mathbb{N}$:
Firstly, let $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ be a parametrization of the unit circle. Now, given a smart partition of $[a,b]$ (which I am also currently still seeking), $a=t_0<\dots<t_N=b$, into $N$ subintervals (or maybe something else with $N$ makes it easier?) we define the polygon $P^N:=(p_0,\dots,p_N)$, where $p_0=\gamma(a)$. Now, if we know $p_{n-1}$, we get $p_n$ by choosing it as intersection point of the lines $p_{n-1}+\mathbb{R} \gamma'(t_{n-1})$ and $\mathbb{R} \gamma(t_n)$.
If we were to draw it, we would see that with every edge of $P^N$ we slowly but surely move away from the unit circle. However, it also seems rather obvious, that with increasing $N$ we get as close to the circle as we wish to. Well, showing it rigorously is a different story.
The task is to show that $P^N\rightarrow \gamma$ uniformly. Therefore, I have thought of writing $P^N$ as follows:
$$
P^N(t)=\sum_{n=1}^N\Big( p_{n-1} + \frac{t-t_{n-1}}{t_n-t_{n-1}}(p_n+p_{n-1})\Big)\chi_{[t_{n-1},t_n]}(t).
$$
Sadly, this still does not help me achieve uniform convergence.
Also, I have thought of more geometric approaches by applying Law of Cosines, which might be of help, but in my attempts I had the issue of summing up $N$ times, which is an obstacle when trying to approximate to a given tolerance $\epsilon>0$.
Lastly, note that showing $P^N(b)\rightarrow \gamma(b)$ is sufficient, since the maximum distance happens precisely at the end.

I have thought of this, Too. Yet, this does Not get me any Further than what I Said in the Question.
